# Union of Two Solid Tori

Tags: general-topology, spheres

I see that the 3-sphere $S^3$ can be thought of as $\partial D^4 \cong \partial(D^2 \times D^2) = (\partial D^2 \times D^2) \,\cup\, (D^2 \times \partial D^2)$, but I am confused to what the actual union means. Does it mean glue their boundaries together?

Comment: Yes, this is the meaning. Or you can say that the sphere is a union of two subsets each of which is homeomorphic to the solid torus and which intersect along their respective boundaries.

Comment: @MoisheKohan To verify, I would be identifying each point on the boundary of the solid torus (this boundary is just the regular hollow torus) to every other boundary point on the other solid torus?

Comment: Right. But you have to be careful which identification (homeomorphism) to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation $\partial (D^2 \times D^2) = (\partial D^2 \times D^2) \,\cup\, (D^2 \times \partial D^2) = (S^1 \times D^2) \cup (D^2 \times S^1)$ does not mean that anything is glued. $\partial (D^2 \times D^2)$ is the union of two genuine subspaces $\Theta_ 1 = S^1 \times D^2$ and $\Theta_ 2 = D^2 \times S^1$ of $\partial (D^2 \times D^2)$ intersecting in $T  = (S^1 \times D^2) \,\cap\, (D^2 \times S^1) = S^1 \times S^1$ which is a torus lying in $\partial (D^2 \times D^2) \subset D^2 \times D^2 \subset \mathbb R^4$.

However, it shows that $S^3$ is homeomorphic to the quotient space obtained from the disjoint union ot two solid tori by gluing their boundaries via a suitable homeomorphism. To see this, let $$Q = (\Theta_1 \times \{1\} \cup  \Theta_2 \times \{2\} )/ \sim$$
where $\sim$ is generated by $(x,1) \sim (x,2)$ for $x \in T$. We can also write it as the adjunction space
$$Q = \Theta_1 \cup_i  \Theta_2$$
obtained by attaching $\Theta_1$ to $\Theta_2$ via the inclusion $i : T \hookrightarrow \Theta_2$.

The map
$$p : \Theta_1 \times \{1\} \cup  \Theta_2 \times \{2\} \to \partial (D^2 \times D^2), p(x,i) = x ,$$
is a quotient map whose fibers are singletons for $x \notin T$ and  $\{ (x,1), (x,2) \}$ for $x \in T$. Hence $p$ induces a homeomorphism $Q \to \partial (D^2 \times D^2)$.

**Remark:** The result of the gluing process depends on the choice of a homeomorphism $h : T \to T$ which induces an attaching map $i_h = i \circ h : T \to \Theta_2$. Our above attaching map is obtained for $h = id$. See Moishe Kohan's comment.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary of a solid torus is the regular hollow torus. So if you have $2$ solid tori, you can pick an isomorphism that maps the boundary of one to the boundary of the other. This is your glueing map. Note that the isomorphisms fall into two topologically distinct classes. One glues the two solid tori to $S^3$, the other one gives $S^2 \times S^1$.

Comment: In fact, there are infinitely many isotopy classes of homeomorphisms $T^2\to T^2$. They form a group isomorphic to $GL(2, Z)$. Accordingly, one obtains infinitely many 3-dimensional manifolds using such homeomorphisms; most of these manifolds are known as [Lens Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space) $L(p,q)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan You are right, there are more than two classes. The two I gave are the two simplest ones where you either glue the boundary circles of the solid disks onto each other or glue the boundary of the solid disks onto the circles $\partial D^2$.